# program can't read decimal number that starts with 0.xxx

Tags: c#

I tried to make a simple formula calculator, however when I input decimal starts with 0.xxx the program read it only the xxx.
Here's the code

```
using System;

namespace Tes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double eff, powerf, pow, volt;
            double result;
            Console.Write("Enter the value of voltage ");
            volt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the value of power in kW ");
            pow = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the value of efficiency in decimal ");
            eff = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the value of power factor ");
            powerf = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            result = (pow*1000/3) / ((volt/Math.Sqrt(3))* eff * powerf);

            Console.WriteLine("The Ampere is " + result);
            Console.WriteLine("Volt is " + volt + "\n" + "efficiency is " + eff + "\n" 
                + "Power factor is " + powerf);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX8CQ.jpg) which is wrong.
How can I manage to get the program to read it correctly?

Comment: Why are you using int.Parse when volt is declared as double?

Comment: Also use culture info. Typing in "0.456" on a German system (or any not using "." as decimal separator) will not end up as expected.

Comment: Also, it seems that your culture uses a comma as decimal separator, so try entering "0,87" or specify a specific culture in the Parse method call.

Comment: Have you considered your culture? You should specify it when parsing.

Comment: And as a sidenote: A completely failed parse leads to an exception here. I'd recommend using one of the `.TryParse()` overloads.

Comment: I forgot to edit that when I messing around the data type (try changing double to decimal etc.) Turns out, the problem is the separator (my system use ","). Thank you for the help :)

Comment: You could change the culture at the beginning of your application with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`. For some reason `CurrentUICulture` is not effective in a console app, but `CurrentCulture` works.